# Devise update_attribute on create from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an application where the use case is: Someone can sign up for an account  as an admin. That admin can invite other users.

I have a `User` model with a column `admin` that defaults to false. I use `devise_invitable` gem to handle invitations. When someone signs up, the admin column should be true. When the admin invites a user, the gem creates a user that has admin => false, therefor being a regular user and not having permission to invite other users.

I did this by overriding devise's controllers like such:

```
#registrations_controller.rb
def create
 super
 current_user.update_attribute :admin, true
end
```

Now I want to pass this behavior to the model (Fat model, skinny controller) but I can't use `current_user` in the model as its only accessible to views, helpers and controllers.

Comment: what do you mean `when someone uses the Registerable module`?

Comment: When someone signs up

Comment: When someone signs up the `User` is created. Why not just set `admin` to default to `true`?

Comment: Because I'm using the `devise_invitable` gem which lets a user with admin => true invite other users, the  gem creates a user with admin defaulting to false, hence that invited  user is a standard user

Comment: That makes more sense, those are details you should add to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models don't have access to view helper methods like `current_user`. As far as I can think an `after_create` callback on `User` won't work because a `User` doesn't know and doesn't care if it's being created by registration or invitation. You could define a new `User.create_as_admin` method

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.create_as_admin(params = {})
    params.merge(admin: true)
    create(params)
  end
end
```

But this would require overriding more of the `RegistrationsController#create` action to use `User.create_as_admin` instead of `User.create`, which would really defeat the purpose of keeping the controller lean, and could introduce bugs if you don't know exactly how that method works.

If you want to "skinny up" the controller, I think the best thing to do is extract it into a concern.

In `app/controllers/concerns/admin_creatable.rb`

```
module AdminCreatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_action :update_user_as_admin, only: :create
  end

  def update_user_as_admin
    current_user.update admin: true
  end
end
```

In your `RegistrationsController`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include AdminCreatable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to the model to make the user an admin:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # model
  ...
  def make_admin!
    update(admin: true)
  end
end

class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    current_user.make_admin!
  end
end
```

Be aware that this will throw an error if the `current_user` is nil!